# Call to PageMethod blocks until complete; prevents client or server-side redirect

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, pagemethods

I'm calling a static Page method via javascript that takes between 5s and 10 min. I'd like to give my user the choice to either continue waiting for the request to complete or not, and use window.setTimeout() to check back every 30s.

I've tried both location.href = '/newpage.aspx' or firing a button's click handler (which does similar redirect) to redirect the user prior to completion of the page method, to no avail. I *can* immediately send user to a simple html page, but a redirect to any aspx page involving server-side appears to block. When the page method finally completes, the redirect does succeed.

Is this:

- a browser issue? If all modern
  browsers support at least 2
  concurrent requests per domain, why
  wouldn't this work?
- a framework
  limitation?
- a desirable design
  pattern or even possible? I've
  checked, and after redirecting to an
  HTML page, the original request continues processing (db updates, no problem).

Are Page method calls simply not asynchronous from a "concurrent HTTP request" perspective?

Any insight greatly appreciated!

Comment: What led you to believe that they were asynchronous?

Comment: Page methods are certainly asynchronous. For all intents and purposes, they're identical to ASMX ScriptService WebMethods, but with EnableSession set to true by default instead of false.

Comment: @John: I took them to be async in that control is returned immediately to the client side js that calls the page method, but maybe you're on to something. If I were to call the page method during a standard postback from server-side code, the method would certainly not be async as written.

Comment: @Dave: standard ScriptService WebMethods are synchronous.

Comment: @John: In relation to the question he's asking about concurrent HTTP requests, there's nothing inherent to ScriptServices and page methods that block concurrent requests. Here's an example of making requests to an ASMX ScriptService that contains a 50ms delay, 100 times, as fast as Firefox will allow: http://i.imgur.com/dfm7x.png.  If there were synchronous blocking on the server-side, that would take at least 5,000ms, but it usually finishes in around 750ms here. The browser's per-domain connection limit is all that's holding it back.

Comment: @Dave: they are sync in the sense that they execute to completion end then return any results. I did not mean that they block callers.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're blocking on InProc Session, which is limited to one concurrent request per unique session. If you don't need access to the Session in your page method, you can disable it by modifying the WebMethod attribute:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession=false)]
```

Comment: Thanks Dave... I tried this to no avail. The redirect still blocks waiting for the PageMethod call to complete.

Comment: Also, just checked and realized we are using out of proc session (sql) session.